# Wald's identity independence of stopping time $N$

Tags: expected-value, stopping-times

I am a bit confused about Wald's identity. In [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/fa17/wald.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee126/fa17/wald.pdf) and [https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/math100w13/hein.pdf](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Epw/math100w13/hein.pdf) it says that the stopping time, $N$, is dependent on $X_1, \ldots, X_N$, which are IID, but independent of $X_{n+1}, \ldots,$.

However, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#Basic_version, it states "$N$ be a nonnegative integer-value random variable that is INDEPENDENT of the sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$".

Now I'm not clear on what $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ actually means, but it seems to be implying that $N$ is independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_N$, which would contradict the first two links. Could someon explain?

Comment: You are reading the "Basic version" section of the Wikipedia page. Go farther down to the "General version" section.

Comment: @angryavian I see. So in the "General Version," it seems the only independence is in assumption (2), which is that $N$ is independent of $X_N, \ldots,$?

Comment: No, (2) is not the same as "$N$ is independent of $X_N$." As "Discussion of Assumptions" mentions, (2) is satisfied when $N$ is a stopping time for the sequence $(X_n)_n$.

Comment: @angryavian I'm confused. What is $(X_n)_n$ here? Is it $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ or, is it $X_1, \ldots, X_N, X_{N+1}, \ldots X_{\infty}$?

Comment: The entire sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah okay. By definition, $N$ is independent of $X_{N+1}$ and beyond right? This is the whole point of "stopping rules" from my understanding. Technically something like $X_{N+1}$ wouldn't even exist since we stop at $X_N$. Maybe the distinction here is that $N$'s independency of $X_{N+1}$ and beyond is governed by the definition of stopping rule and not Wald's equality.

Comment: No, condition (2) and the definition of stopping time are not statements about independence of $N$ and $X_N$. Check the definitions carefully. From the Berkeley notes, $N$ is a stopping time for $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ if $\mathbf{1}\{N \ge n\}$ is a function of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ (note that this is $X_n$, **not** $X_N$). Similarly, condition (2) is a statement about independence of $\mathbf{1}\{N \ge n\}$ (**not** $N$) and $X_n$ (**not** $X_N$).

Comment: @angryavian Okay, I think I got it now. i was getting $n$ and $N$ confused. In the Berkeley, notes, I believe $1_{N \geq n}$ is a function of $X_1, \ldots, X_{n - 1}$, and not of $X_n$ because $1_{N \geq n} = 1 - 1_{N \leq n - 1}$, so $X_n$ and $1_{N \neq n}$ are independent, which is what condition (2) says as well.

Answer (score 1):

Arg sorry, In my last comment I should have written $\mathbf{1}\{N \le n\}$ the first time as in the Berkeley notes (but it is $\mathbf{1}\{N \ge n\}$ for condition (2)), sorry for the confusion.

In any case, here is why a stopping time

> $$\text{for each $n$, }\mathbf{1}\{N \le n\} \text{ is a function of } X_1, \ldots, X_n,$$

satisfies condition (2) on the Wikipedia page

> $$\text{for each $n$, }E[X_n \mathbf{1}\{N \ge n\}] = E[X_n] P(N \ge n).$$

By the definition of a stopping time, $\mathbf{1}\{N \le n-1\}$ is a function of $X_1 ,\ldots, X_{n-1}$ and is independent of $X_n, X_{n+1}, \ldots$. Since $\mathbf{1}\{N \ge n\} = 1 - \mathbf{1}\{N \le n-1\}$, this random variable is also independent of $X_n, X_{n+1}, \ldots$. Thus (2) holds for this $n$.

Comment: I have a question regarding $E[X_n 1\{N \geq n\}] = E[X_n] P(N \neq n)$. If you look at the derivation under theorem 2 of the Berkeley notes, at the first line of the derivation, we get $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[X_n 1\{N \geq n\}]$. But instead of  using $E[X_n 1\{N \geq n\}] = E[X_n] P(N \neq n)$, they used the tower rule for expectations. Are they suggesting that $E[X_n 1\{N \geq n\}] \neq E[X_n] P(N \neq n)$ by doing that? Otherwise, I'm not sure why they took a convoluted approach by using the tower rule, dealing with conditional expectations, and such.

Comment: @student010101 I'll assume that every instance of "$N \ne n$" in your comment is actually "$N \ge n$." The version of Wald's Theorem in the Berkeley notes assumes $N$ is a stopping time. The version of Wald's Theorem on Wikipedia is more general and makes a weaker assumption (2) instead of assuming $N$ is a stopping time. In the Berkeley notes, one uses the tower rules to essentially prove (2) as an intermediate step in the proof; you can't use (2) directly since you have not assumed it.

Comment: Hmm but if Berkeley assumes $N$ is a stopping time, then doesn't that effectively mean that $1\{N \geq n\} = 1 - 1\{N \leq n - 1\}$ is unconditionally independent of $X_n$?